# Table cell subtitles not displaying

Tags: objective-c, ios, cell, subtitle

I setup the cell style to subtile in the inspector but still no subtitles, just blank but the title is displayed
 here is the section in the view controller:

```
  - (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath;
{

UITableViewCell *cell = nil;

cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"homeworkcell"];

if(cell == nil)
{
    cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault  reuseIdentifier:@"homeworkcell"];

}
cell.textLabel.text = [tabledata objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
cell.detailTextLabel.text = [tablesubtitles objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
cell.textLabel.font = [UIFont systemFontOfSize:14.0];

 //static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";

  /* if (cell == nil) {
    cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc]
            initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleSubtitle
            reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
  }*/

 // Configure the cell.
 //-----------------------------------------START----------------------------Set image of  cell----
  cellImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"checkboxblank.png"];

 cell.imageView.image = cellImage;

 //--------------------------------------------END---------------------------end set image of cell--  

 return cell;

}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to use the `UITableViewCellStyleSubtitle` when you create a new `UITableViewCell`, not `UITableViewCellStyleDefault`.  `UITableViewCellStyleDefault` only shows the `textLabel` in the cell, not the `detailTextLabel`.

See the "Cell Styles" section of the [UITableViewCell](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#DOCUMENTATION/UIKit/Reference/UITableViewCell_Class/Reference/Reference.html) reference and the "Standard Styles for Table View Cells" of the [Table View Programming Guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/userexperience/conceptual/TableView_iPhone/TableViewStyles/TableViewCharacteristics.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007451-CH3-SW1).